# Homebrew on Linux - brew install not seeing existing packages

Tags: homebrew

I'm using Home Brew on my system to allow users to install some packages;  there are some that are installed at the system level (e.g. build-essential) but when I run a formula brew is not able to see them and download them. Is this the expected behavior or is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the packages you’re installing? Homebrew doesn’t use software not installed by itself because it can’t know for sure it was built as it expects it to be. If you’re using custom packages you should be able to modify them to use already-installed software.

Comment: @bfontaine `brew install cmake` downloads `openssl` even if it's there, yesterday I tried a recipe for `openalpr` and it reinstalled python2.7 and 3.6 even if they were available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an expected behavior. Homebrew on Linux, namely Linuxbrew, uses its own libraries.

> Homebrew does not use any libraries provided by your host system, except glibc and gcc if they are new enough. Homebrew can install its own current versions of glibc and gcc for older distributions of Linux.

References

- [Homebrew documentation of Linuxbrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux)